# trackbar appearance with backcolor

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, winforms, trackbar

[image]

How to make a trackbar like this picture? If its unachiveable with the trackbar, what other methods are there to achieve something similar?

I would have a sql populate the values too.. any suggestion on how to approach this?
An example would be for PH reading we have a set of values to be maximum and minimum, the slider would be the current value of the object. The green zone is the first warning values, the yellow is the danger values.

Comment: This is a very vagues question. In fact, these are two different questions. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have tried searching on how custom trackbars are being used but found non applicable to what I am trying to achieve. I would really need the first question to be dealt first mainly as the appearance is what i need now.

Comment: Sounds like a specialized, custom control because it seems like there are 2 scales: Plus and Minus from a TargetValue.  Next define properties to represent the Warning and Danger ranges, probably as percentages.  Then when you paint, the current color would depend on `Math.Abs(CurrentValue - TargetValue)`.  If you use gradient painting, the colors could fade from one to the next.  I'd also use a pointer rather than a black bar segment which lacks precision and since you have that nice scale on the side.

Answer (score 0):

I found two links by which you can customize TrackBar in C# visual studio. It is not the exact solution to your question but I believe if you play around with this u can find out what you want.

[Code Project .com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7974/A-variation-on-the-default-TrackBar)

[ViBlend](http://www.viblend.com/forum/d_postsm165_Customizing-TrackBar-s-Appearance.aspx#post165)

Regards